# iOS find the most common record in core data?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I want to be able to look through all the attributes of an Entity and find the most popular one. I know it has something to do with **NSPredicate**, but I can't quite wrap my mind around to achieve it.

**One possible solution:**
*Fetch all the entities and loop through it and sort the attributes into different arrays, from there count the items in the arrays to determine the most popular/common one.*

**Although this might work I'm just wondering if there's an easier or *'cleaner'* way of doing it.**

### Update:

Thanks @Caleb. Let me clarify, **I'm looking for a single attribute value that's most often used by instances of a given entity.**

Comment: What do you mean by most popular?

Comment: Please define "most popular." Are you looking for a single attribute value that's most often used by instances of a given entity? Are you looking for a set of values that's most often repeated? Or are you looking for the instance of an entity that's related to the most other objects?

Comment: Thanks @Caleb, I'm looking for a single attribute value that's most often used by instances of a given entity. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

That is really a dirty descision.

I would suggest you to make a new entity, say, `AttributeCounter`, with two attributes - `name` and `count`, and every time you add an attribute to a person, change this entity.

But that would only be good descision if you have a few different attributes and lots of persons. If not, here is another approach, that is quite simple:

1. Get all the enteties with first attribute not nil,count,add to array
2. Sort it
3. Here you are

Comment: I'll give this a try, but I thought that there would be an easier way to do this with core data and NSPredicate. Thanks, I'll let you know how well I get on.